# In Lords of Waterdeep on iOS, why does placing a corruption token on The Palace of Waterdeep indicate you won't get to take the Ambassador?

Tags: lords-of-waterdeep, ios

This question is prompted by the iOS implementation of the game by Playdek, so it may just be a flaw in the game, but I'm just checking to make sure there isn't some rule that I'm not aware of.

Here's the scenario: "Delver's Folly" and "The Palace of Waterdeep" are in play. I already have an agent on The Palace from a previous turn. (The Palace allows you to place the Ambassador at the start of the next turn.) It's my turn and I place an agent on Delver's Folly, which then allows me to place a corruption token on any action space. I want to place the token on The Palace, but when I do so, the game pops up a message that says "You will not receive the Ambassador. Are you sure you want to take this action?" It sounds like this will negate my previous play of putting an agent on The Palace, but that doesn't make any sense to me. Is there some reason this should be the case, or is this likely a flaw in the iOS version of the game?

Comment: Did you try saying "yes" and seeing what happened? My guess is that it's just a reminder that what you're doing to the location is different from placing an Agent there.

Comment: I'm in the middle of an online game, so I'd rather not do it if it's going to mess up my previous move. I also thought it might be what you said, but it doesn't seem to give a message like that for any other action space. Plus, it's quite specific about the Ambassador. It sure seems deliberate, just not sure why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I posted the question to Playdek support. They said it is a bug in the UI. The message is intended for when an agent is assigned to The Place after someone else has already taken the Ambassador, but before they've had a chance to use it. In that case, the player assigning the new agent does not get to take the Ambassador (see page 22). It is incorrectly being displayed when placing a corruption token (probably any cube) on The Palace. They said selecting "yes" would have worked correctly, i.e. it would not have canceled the earlier play (I had already made an alternate move, so I couldn't confirm), and that it should be fixed in a future release.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the situation they're trying to cover, either. As far as I understand it, no matter how you get an agent onto the Palace, you take the Ambassador -- even if it means stealing it from someone who already took it this turn.

Comment: No, that's not the case. See page 22 of the rulebook: "If another player assigns an Agent to the Palace of Waterdeep after you have taken the Ambassador but before you have had a chance to assign it, he or she gains no benefit from that action." If the Ambassador is placed first, then assigning a new agent to The Palace does allow you to pick it up. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Ah OK, I guess I was wrong about that; never came up for me before.